# How to create vertical tab using in css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

im creating Vertical tab element by using css and jquery, but i need to show first tab content on page load. i use following line to show first element but its not working.

```
$('#v-nav>div.tab-content:first-child').show();
```

im get Vertical tab code from below link, please refer

http://jsfiddle.net/frabiacca/7pM7h/5/

please correct this code to show first tab-content to be default/ onload.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle's code is working fine to me.

Comment: reload the Result frame only or try the code in separate file.

Comment: Updated your code http://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/gb0m2thp/1/ try this. Just added ```active``` class to your pre-selected ```div``` and ```display: block;``` for the ```active``` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a default `active` class to the `div` and styling `display:block;` to the `.active` class.

```js
$(function() {
    var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
            items.removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            //hide all content divs and show current one
            $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show('fast');

            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
        });
    });

    if (location.hash) {
        showTab(location.hash);
    }
    else {
        showTab("tab1");
    }

    function showTab(tab) {
        $("#v-nav ul li:[tab*=" + tab + "]").click();
    }

    // Bind the event hashchange, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
    $(window).hashchange(function() {
        showTab(location.hash.replace("#", ""));
    })

    // Trigger the event hashchange on page load, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```

```css
body
{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.wrapper h1, .wrapper h4, .wrapper p, .wrapper pre, .wrapper ul, .wrapper li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
.wrapper h1 {
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}


.wrapper li
{
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition-property: background color;
    -moz-transition-property: background color;
    -o-transition-property: background color;
    -ms-transition-property: background color;
    transition-property: background color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.12s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.12s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.12s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.12s;
    transition-duration: 0.12s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

#v-nav
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    color: #333;
    font: 12px/18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#v-nav >ul
{
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-right-width: 0;
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    padding:0;
}

#v-nav >ul >li
{
    width: 180px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #F2F1F0;
    font-size: 1.11em;
    position: relative;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 15px !important;  
    background: whiteSmoke; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f2f2f2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #f2f2f2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f2f2f2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f2f2f2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f2f2f2 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f2f2f2 100%); /* W3C */       
}

#v-nav >ul >li.current
{
    color: black;
    border-right: none;
    z-index: 10;
    background: white !important;
    position: relative;
    moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px #fafbfd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px #fafbfd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px #fafbfd;
}

#v-nav >ul >li.first.current
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

#v-nav >ul >li.last
{
    border-bottom: none;
}

#v-nav >div.tab-content
{
    margin-left: 210px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    padding: 12px;
    moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px #fafbfd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px #fafbfd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px #fafbfd;
    display: none;
    padding: 25px;
}

#v-nav >div.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}

#v-nav >div.tab-content >h4
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #F2F1F0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #EEEDED;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>
<section id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="title">I servizi offerti da Evermind</h1>
    <div id="v-nav">
      <ul>
        <li tab="tab1" class="first current">Fatti il sito</li>
        <li tab="tab2">Rifatti il look</li>
        <li tab="tab3">Organizzati</li>
        <li tab="tab4" class="last">Parla di te</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content active">
        <h4><a href="http://www.evermind.it/?areaservizio=fatti-il-sito">Fatti il sito</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h4><a href="http://www.evermind.it/?areaservizio=rifatti-il-look">Rifatti il look</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h4><a href="http://www.evermind.it/?areaservizio=organizzati">Organizzati</a></h4>   
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h4><a href="http://www.evermind.it/?areaservizio=parla-di-te">Parla di te</a></h4>                
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```